# XSLT: Sum of specific attribute value based on other attribute's name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML document (provided by a different party)

```
<transactions>
  <transaction TaxAType="11" TaxAValue="111" TaxBType="2" TaxBValue="222" TaxCType="3" TaxCValue="333"/>
  <transaction TaxAType="11" TaxAValue="111" TaxBType="2" TaxBValue="222" TaxCType="3" TaxCValue="333"/>
</transactions>
```

I would like to write an XSLT document that would transform these lines and sum up the Tax*Value if the corresponding Tax*Type = '11' for example.

Is this something possible without using a template?

name(), substring(), etc. functions in the XQuery?
What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What should the result look like? Just a single number? Some XML with the totals? You say "Tax*Type = '11' for example". Does that mean that in your example XML, the TaxBValue and TaxCValue would not be summed?

Comment: Well the idea is that I would store the Sum of all values for a type of 10 in an attribute of my transformed document. For example <batch gstAmount=5433"> transformed-transactions-elements </batch>

Comment: That doesn't clarify the question much. Where did the type "10" come from this time around? How did you arrive at the result 5433? Could you describe what you want to do, in detail? Given the sample XML you put in your question, what should be the output?

Comment: So if GST is equal to tax type 11 then the gstAmount would be 222. The issue is that tax type 11 could be stored in TaxAType and/or TaxBType and/or TaxCType

Comment: I see now.  Thank you for clarifying. I've posted a generic solution below in case you're interested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">

    Sum of TaxA where type = 11:
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(transactions/transaction[@TaxAType='11']/@TaxAValue)" />

    Sum of all tax where type = 11:
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(transactions/transaction[@TaxAType='11']/@TaxAValue) 
      + sum(transactions/transaction[@TaxBType='11']/@TaxBValue) 
      + sum(transactions/transaction[@TaxCType='11']/@TaxCValue)" />

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It computes sum of TaxAValue for nodes with TaxAType = 11 and sum of all Tax?Value for nodes with Tax?Type = 11.

Comment: This works! Thank you... I was thinking of using a more generic approach using a User-defined function but as the Schema is pre-defined, this would work!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat verbose, but general approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="taxType" select="11" />

  <xsl:template match="transactions">
    <result>
      <xsl:variable name="allValues" 
                    select="transaction/@*[substring(local-name(), 5, 5) = 'Type']
                                          [. = $taxType]" />
      <xsl:call-template name="SumValues">
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$allValues" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SumValues">
    <xsl:param name="items" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($items)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="currentItem" select="$items[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="currentValue">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentItem" mode="getMatchingValue" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:call-template name="SumValues">
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total +  $currentValue" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="getMatchingValue">
    <xsl:variable name="typeCodeLetter" select="substring(local-name(), 4, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="valueAttributeName"
                  select="concat('Tax', $typeCodeLetter, 'Value')" />
    <xsl:variable name="matchingValueAttribute"
                  select="../@*[local-name() = $valueAttributeName]" />

    <!-- Multiply by boolean to handle the case where the 
         attribute wasn't found-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$matchingValueAttribute * 
                          boolean($matchingValueAttribute)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should be able to handle any number of `Tax*Type`s (as long as * is a single character) and the desired type can be passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This xml is not in a very format suitable for completing the type of processing you are asking to do. 
your best option is to use javascript or some other  language with XML capabilities (C#, Java,etc etc) to extract the details you need.

with javascript you could find any attribute with Tax*Type=11 and then get the value of the next attribute

Comment: I believe it's not pure XSL but I might have found a reasonable approach creating a User-Defined Function which would receive a nodelist of all attributes with matching name Tax?Type with a value of 11, The UDF would then look and sum the "counterpart" being Tax?Value.

Answer (score 0):

sum(transactions/transaction[@TaxAType='11']/@TaxAValue | @TaxBvalue | @ TaxCvalue)